# Android firebase user_dim.user_id==null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

why is it always null? why `FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(ctx).setUserId("lalala id's");` do not set the id to base?

Anyway, I have unique ID's for accounts and I want to sort bigQ firebase analytics by those ID's, but I cant manage to record those ID's somewhere except event it self (which makes query a hell then).

What should I do?s Where to write those ID's?

Answer (score 1):

setUserID should set the user ID as user property, which always accompanies with the events. You can turn on debug mode and look at the traffic on [DebugView](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview) to verify that the User ID is set properly as user property. If user property is null, there probably some errors (invalid characters, too long, etc.) that you may not know.

> To enable Analytics Debug mode on an Android device, execute the
>   following commands:

```
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app <package_name>
```

> This behavior persists until you explicitly disable Debug mode by
>   executing the following command:

```
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app .none.
```